# Folder sharing with python sockets

Tags: python, beginner, networking, network-file-transfer

I am just getting started with python. I wanted to make a folder transfer tool to get familiar with python sockets.

```
import socket, os, sys
print"[*]Enter the IP[*]"
ip = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
port = 9999


# A file sender first
def file_sender(location, client_socket):
    f = open(location, 'r')
    data = f.read()
    print("[*]Sending %s[*]" % location)
    client_socket.sendall(data)
    print("[*]Sent %s[*]" % location)
    f.close()
    client_socket.send("STOP")
    client_socket.recv(4096)


# A file reciver for the reciver
def file_reciver(sv, client):
    f = open(sv, 'a')
    data = client.recv(1024)
    while data:
        f.write(data)
        data = client.recv(1024)
        if "STOP" in data:
            break
    f.write(data[:-4])
    client.send("recived")
    f.close()
    print("[*]Saved %s[*]" % sv)


# A folder sender
def folder_sender(location, client_socket):
    os.chdir(location)
    location = os.getcwd()
    no = len(list(os.listdir(location)))
    client_socket.send(str(no))
    print"[*]Preparing to send %d objects[*]" % no
    res = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print res
    for x in os.listdir(location):
        client_socket.send(x)
        print("[*]Sending %s[*]" % x)
        client_socket.recv(1024)
        # Call the server manager
        server_manager(x, client_socket)
        os.chdir(location)
        print(location)


# A folder reciver
def folder_reciver(sv, client):
    try:
        os.mkdir(sv)
    except:
        print "[*]File %s already exists can't overwrite[*]" % sv
        sys.exit(0)
    os.chdir(sv)
    location = os.getcwd()
    print location
    no = client.recv(1024)
    print ("[*]Preparing to recive %s objects[*]" % no)
    client.send("[*]Ready to recive[*]")
    for x in range(int(no)):
        sv = client.recv(4096)
        print ("Reciving %s" % sv)
        client.send("Recived new object")
    # call the client manager
        client_manager(sv, client)
        os.chdir(location)  # Go to the previous diectory
        print("Saved to %s" % location)


   # Server manager, just seperates files from directories
def server_manager(location, client_socket):
    if os.path.isdir(location):
        client_socket.send("DIR")
        folder_sender(location, client_socket)
    else:
        client_socket.send("not dir")
        file_sender(location, client_socket)


def client_manager(sv, client):
    c = client.recv(4096)
    print c
    if c == "DIR":
        folder_reciver(sv, client)
    else:
        file_reciver(sv, client)


# A sender
def sender():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        server.bind((ip, port))
    except:
        print "[*]Couldn't bind the requested IP[*]"
        sys.exit(0)
    server.listen(1)
    print "[*]Listening to %s : %d[*]" % (ip,port)

    def seer(client_socket):
        re = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print re
        print "[*]The path of the file to send[*]"
        location = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
        server_manager(location, client_socket)
        print("[*]sent all[*]")
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print "[*]Accepted connection form %s : %d[*]" % (addr[0], addr[1])
    seer(client)


# A reciver
def reciver():
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        client.connect((ip, port))
    except:
        print "[*]Coudn't connect to the requested server [*]"
        sys.exit(0)
    client.send("[*]Client is ready to recive[*]")
    print "[*]Where to save the file[*]"
    v = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
    try:
        os.chdir(v)
    except:
        print "[*]No such path/location [*]"
        sys.exit(0)
    print "[*]Save as[*]"
    b = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
    sv = os.path.join(v, b)
    client_manager(sv, client)


while True:
    print "[*]Type s to send or r to recive[*]"
    command = (sys.stdin.readline()).rstrip()
    if command.lower() == "s":
        sender()
    elif command.lower() == "r":
        reciver()
    else:
        print "[*]Invalid Argument: %s" % command
```